# Creating shapefiles using Java and Accumulo

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, java, nosql

I have tracking data with latitude and longitude stored in an Accumulo database table.  We want to move toward using Geoserver for some layer display features on the client side.  Right now I'm looking through the Python script project that will generate shape files.  I'm wondering if anyone has other suggestions on ways I can get down to the basic functions needed to take Lat/Long trails and convert them to shapefiles for geoserver to pick up.

Answer (score 2):

We've taken the approach of implementing WMS and WFS plugins for Geoserver that allow it to be backed by Accumulo.  That way, you can persist your data in one location and access it via OGC standards like WMS/WFS.  As far as converting points to linestrings, depending on the schema of your Accumulo tables, you can use either server side iterators to collect the data into linestrings at query time or you can use aggregators that collect the points into linestrings at ingest time.  This approach leverages the distributed processing capabilities of Accumulo.